# Unable to call member functions

Tags: c++, class, object, codeblocks, member

I'm pretty sure I'm probably doing something stupid, but I've been at this an hour and a half and can't figure out what I'm missing.

I can create an object from my class using the default constructor, but can't use an overloaded constructor when I add one. I can't call the print member function that I have included or any others that I have tried to include either.  I have put the three files into a Code::Blocks project and gotten the same result.  I have also tried the three files on Dev-Cpp with the same result.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Main Function

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Appt.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Appt a();
    a.print();
}
```

Appt.h

```
#ifndef APPT_H
#define APPT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>    
using namespace std;

class Appt
{
    public:
        Appt();

        void print();

    private:
        string description;
};

#endif // APPT_H
```

Appt.cpp

```
#include "Appt.h"

using namespace std;

Appt::Appt()
{
    description = "No Description";
}

void Appt::print()
{
    cout << description << endl;
}
```

I am using Code::Blocks 16.01 with the GCC compiler.  These files are not currently in a project.  I am also running Windows 7.

Comment: The exact error is an undefined reference to whatever function I'm trying to access.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your problems may be related to this line:

```
Appt a();
```

Unfortunately, while this looks like it calls the default constructor, it actually declares `a` to be of type `Appt()`, that is, a function taking no arguments and returning `Appt`. If you want to call the default constructor, there are a few options:

```
Appt a;
Appt a = Appt();
Appt a{};  // requires C++11
```

I would prefer the last one.

Comment: Oh great! Thank you. Unfortunately that didn't fix my problem though.  Now that I'm calling it correctly, It's simply not finding the default constructor either.